# Unable to display PDF using php - just says LOADING

Tags: php, pdf

Can anyone tell me why I am unable to display a PDF file using PHP?  It says LOADING in lower left corner which never goes away.  I can use the control panel and view the pdf just fine, so I know it's a valid PDF file.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
   session_start();

   $path = '/show_bills/';
// The location of the PDF file on the server.
   $filename = $path.$_SESSION['ShowID']."_show_bill.pdf"; 

   header("Content-type: application/pdf");
   header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename));
   readfile($filename);

   exit;
?>
```

Thanks,

Vic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am almost sure the file just does not exist. You have a trailing slash in the $path meaning the the script will look for the file in the very root of the server

You can check whether the file exists or not using file_exists function

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Also, just try to output the file without specifying headers - probably it outputs a PHP warning

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, you're right says file not found!  Not sure why yet because the filename appears correct and as I said I can view it in control panel.

Comment: This is most probably because of the trailing slash in your $path variable. Change it so it's relative to the script    $path = 'show_bills/'; and it should work